# htaccess Rewrite causing 500 errors

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to do what I thought were a couple of pretty simple redirects, but for some reason the redirects below (and the 1000 other attempts I've tried!) seem to cause 500 errors.

I have managed to get the domain.co.uk to www.domain.co.uk working on it's own, but as soon as I try to add the additional redirect it fails.

Basically, I just want a standard 301 from domain.co.uk to www.domain.co.uk and I also want to temporarily direct www.domain.co.uk to www.domain.co.uk/blog

Any help, much appreciated!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) blog/$1 [R=307, L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd put an answer on here as I wasted hours on this and the issue was ridiculously stupid! So hopefully this saves someone some time:

The issue was being caused by the space that I had put in the second Rewrite Flag:

```
RewriteRule (.*) blog/$1 [R=307, L]
```

See the space before the L above. The following (minus space) fixed the problem:

```
RewriteRule (.*) blog/$1 [R=307,L]
```